# Binomial random distribution & conditional probability

Tags: probability

I have solved following two problems related to binomial distribution probability and conditional probability, but I am unsure that both are correct; especially for c, I have written down

If the mutual fund performance is determined entirely by luck, rather than skill of the manager, each mutual fund has only a 50% probability of beating the S & P 500 each year. If performance is driven by luck, what is the probability that at least one fund will beat the market every year for 10 years?

a) If the mutual fund performance is determined entirely by luck, rather than skill of the manager, each mutual fund has only a 50% probability of beating the S & P 500 each year. If performance is driven by luck, what is the probability that at least one fund will beat the market every year for 10 years?

c) Suppose you are not sure whether skill affects mutual fund performance or not. You notice that five of the 100 funds have beaten the market every year for the last five years. What is the probability of observing at least that many funds beating the market every year for five years, if performance is determined entirely by luck?

[image]

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there are $n$ mutual funds.

Let $B_{t,n}$ be the number of mutual funds that beat the market for $t$ years. Then $B_{t,n} \sim Bin(n,p_t)$. We have to first determine $p$, the probability that a mutual fund beat the market for $t$ years by luck, which would be $0.5^{t}$ by multiplicative law.

For part $a$, we want to compute $$P(B_{n,t} \ge 1) = 1-P(B_{n,t}=0)=1-(1-p_t)^n=1-(1-0.5^t)^n.$$

For part $c$, we are interested in $$P(B_{100,5} \ge 5)=1-\sum_{i=0}^4 P(B_{100,5}=i)=1-\sum_{i=0}^4\binom{100}{i}(0.5^5)^i(1-0.5^5)^{100-i}$$